# How to concatenate a date in MS-excel and receive a date (not a number)

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, date-time, concatenation

When I try to concatenate two cells in MS-excel in the formula I have the date as a integer number (eg: 04 april 2012 become 41006).

How can I display the date also in the formula cells?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the way Excel sees dates. To see them the way you want they have to be formatted and when alone in a cell that can be done by changing the cell's formatting. When you want to combine a date with other things, such as text, you need to use formula to format the date the way you want. Here's how:

Use the TEXT formula to change the date to text in the format you want. If you were concatenating the text `Last run on` with the date in a cell, say A2, then your formula would look like this

```
=CONCATENATE("Last run on ",TEXT(A2,"DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

Of course you don't actually need the concatenate:

```
="Last run on "&TEXT(A2,"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

But the concatenate makes it clear what you're doing.

Either way these would return the value `Last run on 06/11/2013` (if that was the date in question.) You can then change the text pattern to adjust the date format; e.g.

"MM-YY" for 06-11
"DD MMM" for 06 Nov
"DDDD DD MMMM YYYY" for Wednesday 06 November 2013

Comment: I came across this answer when trying to concat cells together with a separator (as per [this](http://superuser.com/questions/387373/merging-columns-in-excel-with-separator) question) and this works for that, as well.

Comment: Worked nicely for other formatting instructions, such as =CONCATENATE("It's ", TEXT(A2,"#.00"), "!")

Comment: One note, if the sheet is in non-english locale, then the formatting codes are also localized, so for example in Finnish you would do "vvvv-kk-pp" as the formatting code.