# Keeping time format in a concatenate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a spreadsheet that shows durations in Column C2 as hh:mm:ss. I need to transfer this to Column N2 in mm:ss. Column N2 is part of a CONCATENATE in Column E2. When I put time in Column N2 it changes into decimal on the CONCATENATE in Column E2. How can I keep it in time format in the CONCATENATE with or without the colons?

Please consider

```
    A                 B
1  10:15:03           Hi it's 0.427453703703704
```

Cell A1 has the value as shown and is formatted as `Time`
B1 has the following

`=CONCATENATE("Hi it's ", A1)`

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: You might just need to set the format of the second cell to a date time format, but with concatenate involved it could be more complicated.  You need better examples for this to be answerable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate a date in MS-excel and receive a date (not a number)](http://superuser.com/questions/670423/how-to-concatenate-a-date-in-ms-excel-and-receive-a-date-not-a-number)

Comment: I made a big change to your post, you can roll it back if you don't like it

Comment: Look at the duplicate question identified by Dave above. That is likely to be your answer. If not update your question with specific changes

Answer (score 4):

this should do it:

`=CONCATENATE("Hi it's ", TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:ss"))`

Use the TEXT function to change the time to human readable, rather than Excels decimal notation.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
=CONCATENATE("Hi its ",TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

[image]